# Exponential decay

Tags: forecasting, exponential-distribution

I have a new product that was launched and I see a bug spike in enrollments during the initial stages post which it's been declining and now it holding steady. Curve looks like an exponential distribution. Based on this data, I am trying to forecast enrollments for upcoming periods. My data is at a day level.

Can somebody please help with the approach I would need to take?

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with your assumption of exponential distribution, your best predictor of enrollment rate is $\hat{\lambda} = n/t$ where $\hat{\lambda}$ is the predictor of enrollment rate, $n$ is the quantity of enrollments for a time period,  $t$ is the related time period (# of days for your case).

With the $\hat{\lambda}$ (such as $42\,/day$) you can forecast whatever you wish such as # of enrollments between day X & Y etc.

You may need to read about *probability density*, *cumulative density* functions for the exponential distribution if you're not familiar with them.